# React application doesn't display anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). I am following [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) example but I am trying to use my own application. When I run this code, nothing displays in browser.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';
import './fixed-data-table-style.css';


// Table data as a list of array.
const rows = [
  ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
  ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
  ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'],
  // .... and more
];

class TableExample extends React.Component {
    renderTable() {
        return(
        <Table
            rowHeight={50}
            rowsCount={rows.length}
            width={5000}
            height={5000}
            headerHeight={50}>
            <Column
            header={<Cell>Col 1</Cell>}
            cell={<Cell>Column 1 static content</Cell>}
            width={2000}
            />
            <Column
            header={<Cell>Col 2</Cell>}
            cell={<Cell mySpecialProp="column2" />}
            width={1000}
            />
            <Column
            header={<Cell>Col 3</Cell>}
            cell={({rowIndex, ...props}) => (
                <Cell {...props}>
                Data for column 3: {rows[rowIndex][2]}
                </Cell>
            )}
            width={2000}
            />
        </Table>)
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div> 
               { this.renderTable() }
            </div> 
        );
    }
}

// Render your table
ReactDOM.render(
  <TableExample /> , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: It's `render` not `renderTable`.

Comment: Huh? render calls renderTable?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that additional `render` at the bottom.

Comment: What are you seeing in the console?  Is render being called at all when you debug it?

Comment: nothing shows on the console except normal feedback. No errors.

Comment: If you inspect the source of the page is anything there?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a method that returns your jsx is not a typical pattern in react. The following should work no problem.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';
import './fixed-data-table-style.css';


// Table data as a list of array.
const rows = [
  ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
  ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
  ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'],
  // .... and more
];

class TableExample extends React.Component {


    render() {
        return ( 
            <div> 
                <Table
            rowHeight={50}
            rowsCount={rows.length}
            width={5000}
            height={5000}
            headerHeight={50}>
            <Column
            header={<Cell>Col 1</Cell>}
            cell={<Cell>Column 1 static content</Cell>}
            width={2000}
            />
            <Column
            header={<Cell>Col 2</Cell>}
            cell={<Cell mySpecialProp="column2" />}
            width={1000}
            />
            <Column
            header={<Cell>Col 3</Cell>}
            cell={({rowIndex, ...props}) => (
                <Cell {...props}>
                Data for column 3: {rows[rowIndex][2]}
                </Cell>
            )}
            width={2000}
            />
        </Table>
            </div> 
        );
    }
}

// Render your table
ReactDOM.render(
  <TableExample /> , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

EDIT: removed some janky code.

Comment: I will try to modify the renderTable function. However, if I modify render to your code, I get, TypeError: this.renderTable(...).bind is not a function.

Comment: Oops, I have to remove the parens from renderTable.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with calling method in render that returns valid jsx.  I dont think this solution is going to fix it.

Comment: I removed that piece for now, because I don't really think there's ever a need to do what you're doing. If you have some conditionals, it's best to do those within the `render()` function and you can manipulate what you want to return there.

Comment: @Ivan please put some debug code in to see that your even making it to render.  Also, maybe return something like this in your render just as a test:   ( <div>hi</div>)

Comment: gut out the `<Table>` components and its children and try to render something. If that works, then something must be wrong with how your implementing the `fixed-data-table` piece. As other say, what are the errors being thrown in the console?

Comment: As terpinmd said - are you able to render a simple <p>hi</p> within the div?

Comment: I removed everything from RenderExample render function and just put  <div>hi</div>.THAT SHOWS. Something is wrong with the "complicated table render", but I don't know why.

Comment: @Christopher, fixed-data-table is something I got from here https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table

Comment: I checked the repo and the very first issue opened is titled "Deprecate this project". Even if you did solve this particular issue, I don't think this is the library you want to be working with.

I've had success with this one: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized - pretty supportive community with a lot of examples floating around - that should be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I am actually looking for a table that can handle real-time updates to the cells.

Comment: @ChristopherMesser I noticed that too....but now I am curious why its not working :)